# ASP.NET MVC: 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, windows-server-2003

I recently deployed an ASP.NET MVC application on a Win server 2008, IIS 7 machine. It has MVC installed, and .NET framework 4.5 installed.
Whenever I publish, and try to log in, I get this annoying error:

```
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is     temporarily unavailable.
```

Meanwhile the controller action - Home/Login is intact and the Login.cshtml page is okay. Plus
the web config file has

```
  modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  assemblies>
     handlers>
    remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>
    remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
    remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
    add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule"  
    /handlers>
```

So I am wondering what is wrong. It is running under Integrated mode, ASP.NET 4.0 app pool.
Static content and dynamic content are both enabled. I guess you can tell I have gone through most of the posts on this issue.:) Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: Are you browsing the site the the same machine that IIS is on? Also, is this a fresh installation of IIS? Are you working in a restricted environment?

Comment: It is on an intranet and the app folder is on a machine that is separate from the one I am browsing from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, I would log onto the server that is hosting the application, Open IIS Manager, find your site and click view in browser. This will ensure that you have the URL correct and should give you more debugging information if something is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks mmill, I did that and discovered that it loads the first page, for Login but when I click the log in button, it gives me the 404 error-The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable-referring to the extensionless url i.e. \Home\Login which should be the next post after logging in. But like I earlier said I added this <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> That is why I am surprised that it is not working for MVC routing.

Comment: Are you using forms or Windows Authentication?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I am using forms authentication.

Comment: I suspect the problem is from some other applications that were deployed on the same Default Web Site [port 80] namely CertSrv,DomainHRA,HCAP, NonDomainHRA,Rpc, RpcWithCert. Could it be these?

Comment: I wouldn't think so because of the fact that the Login page works, but you can always test that by changing your IIS Web Site/Application to use a different port. Also you said you specified .NET 4.0 on IIS, but in your config file is says the target framework is 4.5. May be nothing but it is worth checking

Comment: fixed it by adding to the web.config->modules->runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"

Comment: Wish I could get that browse action in IIS to actually work. Have wanted to test with it many times but it never does anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to add MIME Types if your files have nonstandard extensions.

Fair choices:

```
application/octet-stream
text/plain
```

Without an associated MIME type, IIS just says 404 when you try and download a file which you can clearly see in the directory listing.

Answer (score 0):

I have added below MIME types to web.config under system.webserver, and it's working

```
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <clear />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="text/*" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="message/*" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/x-javascript" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/javascript" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/json" />
        <add enabled="false" mimeType="*/*" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8" />
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <clear />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="text/*" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="message/*" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/javascript" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/xaml+xml" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/json" />
        <add enabled="false" mimeType="*/*" />
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
```